# CPT in a shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm having trouble with putting my custom post type content in the shortcode and was wondering can someone help me with this.

I need this in shortcode:

```
   // List judges shortcode
 function judges_shortcode($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(

    ),$atts ) );

$value='<?php 
                            the_content(); ?>

                            <?php

                            $judges = get_posts(array(
                                'numberposts' => -1,
                                'post_type' => 'judges',
                                'meta_key' => '',
                                'meta_value' => ''
                            ));


                                if ($judges) { ?>

                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                    <?php foreach ($judges as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                    <?php 
                                    $image = get_field('judge_image');
                                    $link = get_field('judge_link');
                                    $socialicon = get_field('judge_social_icon');

                                     ?>
                                            <div class="col">
                                            <ul class="judges d-flex">
                                                <li class="judge">
                                                    <h3 class="text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="" />
                                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                                    <a class="judge-link" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $socialicon ?></a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>    
                                            </div>
                                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                        </div> <!-- end row -->
                                    </div> <!-- end container -->

                                 <?php } ?>';


return $value;
}
add_shortcode('judges','judges_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` for that.  Also it looks like you're not using any attributes so you can ditch the call to `shortcode_atts()`

```
<?php
// List judges shortcode
function judges_shortcode($atts){

    ob_start();

    the_content();
    $judges = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'judges',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => ''
    ));

    if ($judges) { ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($judges as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <?php
                    $image = get_field('judge_image');
                    $link = get_field('judge_link');
                    $socialicon = get_field('judge_social_icon');

                    ?>
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul class="judges d-flex">
                            <li class="judge">
                                <h3 class="text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="" />
                                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                <a class="judge-link" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $socialicon ?></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end container -->

    <?php };

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('judges','judges_shortcode');
```

Comment: tnx for the comment @mrben522
sadly getting a 503 Service Unavailable :/